# LINK2019 error when trying to use Net-SNMP in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, snmp, net-snmp

So I am trying to follow along with the "snmpdemoapp" on the Net-SNMP website and I am getting the LINK2019 error when trying to use:

```
init_snmp("snmpdemoapp");
```

Link to demo app: http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/TUT:Simple_Application

If I comment this line out, then it will build successfully. I am also using Visual Studio 2015. I have the Net-SNMP library in my references. I am also not using the library in a "main()" function.

Comment: Is your C code managed or unmanaged?  If it's unmanaged, you'll need to bridge the two models.

Comment: @Steve How would I figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the error by including:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "netsnmp.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "netsnmpagent.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "netsnmpmibs.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "netsnmptrapd.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Advapi32.lib")
```